# Can't access data.ext without “Unexpected end of archive” error

Tags: backup, data-recovery, zip, tar

I have backup data files and want to get some of the files from "data".

However, the backup is split into 3 files:

1. data.ext4.tar (0kb)
2. data.ext4.tar.a (1gb)
3. data.ext4.tar.b (700mb)

How can I access the data without getting the "unexpected end of archive" error?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Just for clarification, as the Android tag states, this question is off topic, unless it specifically involves interaction with a computer. Can you be more specific how you are working with these files? Are you attempting this on the Android device or on a computer?

Comment: This I'm attempting to do on a computer. It can be any file, not necessarily the nandroid backup, but I'm just giving in some context. What I want to do is open these three/two files as one, so I don't get the "unexpected end of archive error" again.

Comment: I edited your question to be more about accessing the data and removed the reference to Android since you are trying to access these files on a computer, not an Android. That tag and wording trips some people up. If you disagree with my edits, you can revert it back.